# How to apply css to img for cropping

Tags: css

I like to have fixed height of parent and then try to place the image inside the parent. I am trying to apply some cropping to images top section. I used margin-top:-10% to img to top section to be cropped. Desktop and tablet, it looks just ok but for mobile I see a big space between the bottom of image and bottom of the parent. I am not sure if I am doing correctly. I am having difficult time fixing the gap. Can you please let me know how to fix the gap or a better way of doing it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zgql.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item"><img src="1.jpg" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
image caption 1
 </div>
 </div>

<div class="item"><img src="2.jpg" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
image caption 2
 </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
}

.carousel-inner img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
margin-top:-10%
}
```

---

**Update**

```
.page-node-76  .main-container.container img {
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
}

.page-node-76 .carousel-inner .item{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    padding: 15% 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.page-node-76 .carousel-inner .item:nth-child(2){
        background: url(http://i50.tinypic.com/24ne1ck.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.page-node-76 .carousel-inner .item:nth-child(1){
        background: url(/sites/default/files/carousel_images/slide2.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.page-node-76 .carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-node-76 .carousel-inner .item div {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: apply fixed small height to container of image and use overflow:hidded ... or use the image as backgound

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

I use `img` as `background`.

```css
.carousel-inner {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner .item {
 background: url(http://i50.tinypic.com/24ne1ck.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 padding: 15% 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.carousel-inner .item div {
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption"> image caption 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption"> image caption 2 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have not tried your code yet. This is for slideshow. I have about 5 slides. That means I will have 5 .item classes. Since you are suggesting to use background image, how  can I set different image background for each .item class. ? Your code shows one background image for all item classes.

Comment: You can use  `.class` or  `:nth-child.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `.class` or  `:nth-child.`

Comment: Updated my post above. 1. There was img inside item class. I forgot to tell you. I hide them by css 2) i used bg img for each item 3) bg image not 100% width. You have used bg size:cover 4. When responsive, dont look right. My page:   http://drupal1.info/drupal1/content/slider3